# Alternatives to the politician theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, alternative-proof

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R and S are invited to a birthday party. We are told that:

- each pair of guests have exactly one common friend
- A and G only have one common friend: C
- A and G are friends
- I and C only have one common friend: A

How many friends does the most popular (in terms of friends) guest have ?

Invoking the [politician/friendship theorem](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hfinkeln/seminarium/politicus.pdf): it is straightforward that A has the most friends (18), as he is the common friend to all the guests.

My question is: can anyone think of an alternative solution to this problem ?

Comment: I'm a bit baffled by this. (1) A&C have 2 common friends, G & I, in violation of the main rule that any two folk have exactly 1 common friend. (2) What purpose is served by the word "only" in two of the rules? We know they can't have more than one. (3) Are we asked to find an alternative proof to the politician theorem? Or some weird way to prove this example which avoids mentioning or proving that someone is everyone's friend? Maybe this is a language thing, but would appreciate clarification, thanks

Comment: You are not the first :)

Comment: @Laska I is not friends with C.

Comment: Yes I realised after posting: the unnecessary word “only” is distracting. I thought the trick must be that some people have two names: or maybe I is first person. Why do you only answer one of my points? And then there’s extra info that someone has added, and you have not even commented on! Please clear up your problem definition thanks

Comment: @Laska (2) you can indeed ommit the word "only" if you want (3)I was wondering at the time if there was a way to solve this puzzle without invoking the friendship theorem. Probably not. And yes someone added extra information, which is correct and useful to invoke the theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution, where $A$ (or $C$) is in the centre of windmill graph is the only solution that gives us 18 friends.

Assume, that A knows everybody. 
Both A and E have to know someone else, let's say F. Then we have the cycle AEF. The 'windmill' solution gives us 9 'separable' cycles with only common A. Let's try two cycles, that aren't 'separable' (have two common vertices) - AEF and AED. Then A and E have two common friends - F and D. The cycles have to be then 'separate'.

Answer (score 2):

I had never encountered this surprising theorem - thanks for posting.

In order to give a concrete example, the question adds some extra conditions. Under these $A$ has at least three friends: $G$ (by the second condition) and $I$ & $C$ (by the third condition). Therefore it is $A$ who is the politician. Note that this implication was invalid until Alex Ravsky added the second condition. Also the first condition ($C$ the common friend of $A$ & $G$) is redundant.

Shorn of these conditions, the ask is for alternative proofs from the one in "The Book in which God keeps the most elegant proof of each mathematical theorem". That's a fair question but a tall ask. Erdős & spectral analysis have both proved very powerful in graph theory, and we are asked to turn our backs on both...

Here's a different approach based on triangles. It doesn't lead to the full result yet, but I will keep playing with it, and maybe it will inspire someone else.

With no assumptions about regularity for now, for any vertex $A$ with degree $d_A$, there are $C(d_A,2)$ unordered pairs of adjacent vertices. We are going to triage each of the $\sum _{A \in G} C(d_A,2)$ cases. Suppose $B$ & $C$ are two vertices adjacent to $A$. There are two possibilities:

(1) If $B$ & $C$ are non-adjacent, then as $A$ is the "sole mutual friend" of $B$ & $C$, there is a one-to-one-correspondence to the set of non-edges in $G$, of which there are $C(n,2) - m$ items.

(2) If $B$ & $C$ are adjacent then, with $A$, the three vertices form a triangle $ K_3$. Because each vertex is the "sole mutual friend" of the other two, each edge in $G$ belongs to exactly one such triangle. And each such triangle is discovered exactly three times in our examination, depending on which of the three vertices is discovered first. So if $m$ is the number of edges in $G$, there are hence $3 \times m/3$ = $m$ items to be counted here.

Adding these two populations: $m + C(n,2) - m = C(n,2)$

So $\sum_{A \in G} C(d_A,2) = C(n,2)$. [Equation *]

If we require also that $G$ is $k$-regular, then we derive:

$n \times C(k,2) = C(n,2)$

=> $n = k^2 - k + 1$, which is indeed an equation from The Book, so we are on the right track.

Equation * is satisfied happily by all the actual (windmill) solutions. If one "politician" vertex $A$ has degree $2p$, and the other $2p$ vertices have degree $2$, for any $p \ge 0$, then $n = 2p+1$. Then:

$C(2p,2) + 2p \times C(2,2) = 2p\times (2p-1)/2 + 2p \times 1 = p(2p-1)+2p = p(2p+1) = C(n,2)$.

Comment: Thanks for sharing !